# Objective C - Como mudar o conteúdo de uma Image View após realizar uma animação

Tags: objective-c, mobile

Implementei uma animação em uma `Image View` e gostaria de saber como mudo sua imagem exatamente após o fim da animação.

## Exemplo:

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    //ANIM . . .
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1]; //TEM DURAÇÃO DE 1 SEGUNDO . . .
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    self.objeto.frame = CGRectMake(95, 100, 62, 62); //OBJETO É UMA IMAGE VIEW . . .
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //NESTE CASO, MUDAR IMAGEM APÓS 1 SEGUNDO . . .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a documentação da Apple, a partir do iOS 4 você pode utilizar animações usando blocos.

Utilizando animações em blocos você pode realizar do seguinte jeito:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duração animations:^{
   //Código para realizar as animações
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Código que será chamado após as animações
}];
```

Agora, utilizando begin/commit, que é como você está fazendo atualmente, você pode adicionar um método que ele chamará após a conclusão da animação. Lembrando que é necessário definir o delegate para que esse método seja chamado ao finalizar.

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finalizouAnimacao)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
```

Recomendo você dar uma olhada na documentação da Apple que fala sobre animações e também nessa resposta do SOen que mostra alguns argumentos do porque utilizar animação em blocos.

[Documentação Apple - Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)

[Shy should I use the block-based animation rather than begin/commit animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135096/why-should-i-use-the-block-based-animation-rather-than-begin-end-animation)